# How to get spcial item in QuickBooks online by Programming

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I've inserted three Customer items into QuickBooks online. I want to find a special item by ids and modify one of the attributes' value. I want to accomplish this by coding in backstage of a application. How can I do this?

This is the connection code that I have:

```
realmId = HttpContext.Current.Session["realm"].ToString();
accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessToken"].ToString();
accessTokenSecret = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessTokenSecret"].ToString();
consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"];
dataSourcetype = IntuitServicesType.QBO;
OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, realmId, dataSourcetype);
DataServices commonService = new DataServices(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for customers as follows:

```
//search based on customer name
var qbdCustomerQuery1 = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery();
qbdCustomerQuery1.Item1ElementName = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item1ChoiceType.FirstLastInside; //Item1ChoiceType.FirstLastEnd   //Item1ChoiceType.FirstLastStart
qbdCustomerQuery1.Item1 = "Popeye";
List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer> CustomerQueryResult = qbdCustomerQuery1.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>(context).ToList<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>();

//search based on customer id

 Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer qboCustomer = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer();
 qboCustomer.Id = new IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "3" };
 IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer> qboCustomerResults = commonService.FindById(qboCustomer) as IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer>;
```

Use the resultset to get the customer object. Modify the values and call Update:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0299_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis